# Chrome image requests stall for 2 seconds, then complete quickly

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

I have an AngularJS app that uses an element's position relative to the viewport to decide whether to display its contents.  I.e. the element is in place but its contents are not added to it until it is determined that the outer element is close enough to the viewport that we want to fill it with content.  We do this to prevent having all the watches necessary to support the content active until we need them.  For most of the shells, the content (when loaded) will consist of both text an an image.

What I'm seeing consistently in Chrome 68 on Mac is this:

If I use the trackpad (mac laptop) to scroll by swiping with 2 fingers, the elements come into view, the text shows up immediately, and all the expected network requests for the images show up in the network tab.  However, the image requests stall for 2 seconds before they actually 'go'.

If, during that 2-second delay, I interact with the page in any way -- scrolling a bit more, clicking, etc., the requests 'go' immediately and the images in the DOM fill in.  Simple mouse moves to do not fix the requests, nor do keystrokes.

If I use the space bar to page down, the requests are processed without delay.  If I drag the scroll bar down, the requests are processed without delay.  It appears to be limited to only those scrolls that are the result of using the trackpad to scroll.

It doesn't matter if the image is in the cache or not.  Requests that are completed from the cache and requests that hit the network are both affected.

I've tried reducing the problem to just the key pieces (pre-sized divs with lazily-loading content) but have not been able to reproduce it outside our app.  It may therefore be related to some complex CSS we have in place.

I have confirmed using the chrome performance tab that there is nothing in my app running during the 2 second delay, nor is there any callback or anything that gets triggered at that 2-second mark.  I.e. all of my code stops, there's a 2 second delay, then the image requests 'go' and the images fill in.

I've confirmed by adding console.log statements to angular itself that no $digest is running and doing something to delay the request (it's not clear to me that it could if it tried -- but it's definitely not).

I've confirmed that it's NOT a browser extension, too.  I have disabled all of them and also tried incognito windows.

I'd really, really like to avoid stripping out large chunks of my app in the hopes of finding some needle in a haystack, so I'm hoping someone has suggestions of what to try.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer in this post:

[Random high content download time in chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47524205/random-high-content-download-time-in-chrome/47684257#47684257)

The short answer is to add this somewhere in your app:

```
$window.addEventListener('mousewheel', (e) => {
  if (e.deltaY === 1) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```